# what does verbose mean in nodemon configuration file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemon

I have a nodemon configuration in my project what does `verbose` mean and what does it do

```
{
  "verbose": true,
  "watch": "./server"
}
```

i have read the readme file of nodemon it doesn't talk about it

Comment: The README file does not necessarily cover every options available for a program. You can often find useful information about its options in the help section.

Answer (score 7):

Verbose means talkative, it's here to make sure you get more information (trace) from nodemon. It's useful when debugging some code.

Exemple without verbose mode:

```
[nodemon] 1.19.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node test.js`
Hello Nodemon
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Exemple with verbose mode activated:

```
[nodemon] 1.19.1
[nodemon] reading config ./nodemon.json
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] or send SIGHUP to 43148 to restart
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node test.js`
[nodemon] forking
[nodemon] child pid: 43150
[nodemon] watching 7 files
Hello Nodemon
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering! If you could update your answer with examples of what type of extra information you get I think your answer would be even better.